# Facebook app friends list Laravel + Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I am using Laravel + Facebook SDK ( https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk) to get a friends list from my app. The weird thing is for some reason that I don't know why, some users I can fetch their friends, some users I can't.

For example, under my own user, I can fetch all my friends who are also using my app.

However, I have created a new user in Facebook just for testing. I've became a friend of this new user. In addition, this user has approved the app in their facebook. As a result, I can't see this user in my friends list and also this new user can't see me in their friends list.

My code base is

```
 $q = \Facebook::get('/me/friends', $token);
 $friends = json_decode($q->getBody())->data;
```

Comment: This question is not relevant to Laravel in any way. You are using Facebook SDK directly, please update question title and remove 'laravel' tag?

Comment: No, as I said, I am using Laravel plus https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk that is a Laravel package.

Comment: that Laravel package is simply a convenient wrapper for the original Facebook SDK. This issue is not related to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Facebook V2.0 upgraded. So you can try like this "user_friends".

[Refer Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out what was wrong! I was logging in the Facebook without the right permission scope.
Every login it must pass as a parameter "user_friends" according to this url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Basically, the code is

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```